# Не запускается скрипт linux: permission denied

Tags: linux, консоль

Нахожусь в папке, где располагается скрипт. Через "sh имя скрипта" он запускается. А через "./имя скрипта". Получаю `permission denied`. По заданию надо чтобы он запустился при ./ (он запускается из другого скрипта, этот скрипт редактировать нельзя)

Answer (score 8):

сделайте скрипт исполняемым с помощью команды

```
chmod +x имяскрипта
```